# How can I work with the fragment in the android tabbed activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have a problem with the android tabbed activity. Working with the Appcompat works fine, but I want to work with the fragment, that is the class that extends Fragment. Please how can I do this

Comment: How about [Google Play Style Tabs using TabLayout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout)

Comment: Ya I have tried that. I said I don't know how to use the fragment part of it. I have solved my problem though. But I still want to know how to use the fragment part of the tabbed layout